# Setting a Property on an object in a Collection

Tags: c#, collections

I have a `abstract` class ...

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    // other properties
    public bool IsTypeDefault {get;set;}
}
```

I have a number of other classes that inherit from `MyClass`, say, `MyClassA`, `MyClassB`, `MyClassC`, etc.

And I have a collection class defined as ...

```
public class MyCollection : List<MyClass>
{
    public SetAsTypeDefault(MyClass item)
    {

    }
}
```

The method `SetAsTypeDefault` should take an object of type `MyClass`, it will search the collection for a items of the same specific type, unset the `IsTypeDefault` on any item it finds where that value is true and then set it as true for the item that matches the passed in parameter.

What I *want* is to stop someone from setting the `IsTypeDefault` value on an individual instance of the collection directly and I can't figure out how to do it.

I can make `IsTypeDefault` readonly, but then I can't set it from the collection class. I can set it as `private set` and have a method set it, but the method needs to be public to be callable from the collection.

I'm only going to the bother of trying to do this 'cos the devs accessing this class are going to be completely out of my control. Nor am I going to be able to review their code and I want to make sure that they don't mess things up.

I appreciate that there I can't stop them from deliberately breaking stuff, for example, using reflection, but if they do this I want it to be because they are doing it on purpose rather than just being careless.

Is it possible?

**A post-Post thought**

I suppose I *could* attach an event to the `IsTypeDefault` property and have the collection class subscribe to the event, have it (the collection) do the verification before allowing (or not) the change to the instance in the collection. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

If both `MyCollection` and `MyClass` are within the same assembly, but the developers using it are not - then its a simple case of making the setter `internal`

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    // other properties
    public bool IsTypeDefault {get; internal set;}
}
```

Comment: A useful suggestion. In this case that would work as they have access to the assembly but only as a reference.