# Setting a get-only property on an object in a collection

Tags: c#

I have a similar issue to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048948/setting-a-property-on-an-object-in-a-collection) that I have class

```
public class MyClass
{
    // other properties
    public bool IsDefault { get; internal set; }
}
```

and I have a collection class defined like

```
public class MyCollection : ICollection<MyClass>
{
    private List<MyClass> _itemList = new List<MyClass>();

    public void SetAsDefault(MyClass item)
    {
        // Make sure no other items are default.
        _itemList.ForEach(x => x.IsDefault = false);

        // Set specified item as default.
        _itemList.Find(x => x.Equals(item)).IsDefault = true;
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that only that single item in `MyCollection` is flagged as the default, while the same time being able to check directly on `MyClass` whether a particular instance is the default. Marking the setter for `MyClass.IsDefault` as `internal` developers outside the assembly can't set `IsDefault`. However, in my case, the developers I want to avoid faultily setting the `IsDefault` property has access inside the assembly, so using `internal`isn't enough.

Are there any clever solutions to this conundrum? I'm completely at a loss here...

Comment: I'd derive from ObservableCollection<MyClass> instead, then seal the MyCollection. You'll have some work to do, but most of the things are under control.

Comment: You could create a static property `public static MyClass DefaultInstance;` and set that instead. That would take the current default instance.

Comment: You're imposing quite a weak contract that only one item can actually be the default.  Also, isn't it conceivable that an item could be the default of one collection but not of an other?  In which case, might it be better to store the default as a property of the collection?

Comment: Do you want to have a global default instance of your class? Or just a default for each collection? If former, you have more problems than the one you've noticed. If latter - why not simply keep that info as a private member of `MyCollection`?

Comment: What is the use case of the IsDefault information, is it really required for the MyClass instance to know that *it is* the default one?

Comment: If you don't trust your coworkers to do a good job then you have a problem that cannot be solved by writing the right code; your untrustworthy coworkers can just change *that* code. If you're having a problem socializing good coding behaviors across a team then that's a management problem, not a coding problem.  Make a better culture of code ownership, code reviews, mutual respect, and so on.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree, except that in this case it is not a matter of untrustworthy coworkers or disrespect, but simply that we are a bunch of physicists with very different coding experience. We are working on some prototype calculation software for research purposes. We write it ourselves because 1) there is a lot of physics in it and 2) we cannot afford a dedicated computer scientist. We're trying to behave as civilized programmers and enforce some software management from the real world but, alas, academic research is driven by other factors than commercial software development...

Comment: @TheInnerLight In this particular case there can be only one default in each collection. Anything else would be unphysical --- it's actually not defaults I'm trying to set, that was just an attempt at clarifying the question. But yes, perhaps an item could be the default of another collection. I can only imagine the use of a single instance of the collection at present, but I can't rule out the use of it in the future either. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: The key question is: can an item be a member of more than one collection? If so then it makes no sense to have an "is default" on the *item*. My advice is to make a list of *invariants*.  Things like "the default item of a collection must be a member of the collection" and "a collection has exactly zero or one default items", and so on, and then write code that (1) maintains your invariants under all transformations, and (2) debug.asserts your invariants frequently, so that you can find bugs.

Comment: If you do that then you become less dependent on getting the compiler to prevent your coworkers from doing the wrong thing because the code itself will do the right thing, and will tell you if someone does something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is really hard to cleanly get right. Since every other developer could just set the Property somewhere else, I would try and turn the problem arround.

You could remove the Objects property and make it a property on the collection. Since someone can retrieve the MyClass instance and set it anyway, you could add a method to your MyCollection that checks wether a MyClass instance is the default in that collection.

Otherwise I don't see any good way to really forbid what you want.

Comment: Based on this answer, and the many good comments to my question, I will instead let the default be stored in the collection. I originally wanted to be able to see if an item at hand was the default, which would work if there was just a single instance of `MyCollection`. However, I cannot rule out multiple instances in the future, which makes storing the property in the items themselves meaningless. If, in the future, I want to maintain a common default item amongst multiple instances of `MyCollection`, I guess I could just make the property static.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get or set instance that is default for specific collection you need property:

```cs
public MyClass Default { get; set; }
```

defined on `MyCollection` class.

If you want to know whether given instance of `MyClass` is default for specific collection you need method:

```cs
public bool IsDefaultFor(MyCollection collection) {
    return collection.Default == this;
}
```

If you require default instance to be member of the collection, add such assertion in setter of `Default` property and `Remove` method.